# Causal implications from a model with poor predictive capabilities

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, predictive-models, causality

I am currently reading McElreath's Statistical Rethinking book. I'm still in Chapter 5 though. I am unsure if this will be addressed later on but I can't help but wonder:

Earlier in the book, he mentions that a predictive model can have false causal implications. For example, a predictive model on the number of shark attacks based on ice cream sales does not imply that ice cream sales cause shark attacks.

In chapter 5, an example of multiple linear regression is used to eliminate the causal models inconsistent with the data. The context is on divorce rates and its relation to marriage rates and age at marriage. Using multiple linear regression, the consistent causal model, at least in this chapter, is that age influences both divorce rates and marriage rates such that when a regression model is constructed with age and marriage rates as predictors, the coefficient of marriage rate has uncertainty intervals that include 0. I.e. marriage rate is predictive but not causal. For this example, the $R^2$ seems to be high (at least 0.5 although it is not computed) and it appears that the model has reasonable predictive performance.

This got me wondering: if a model has poor predictive capabilities (say for exaggeration, the $R^2$ is less than 0.3 which, from what I read, is common in medicine). Let's suppose as well that when the residuals vs predicted values are plotted, there is no pattern, i.e. the assumptions of linear regression are reasonable. To what extent can we trust the causal implications of this model?

Am I asking the wrong question?

Answer (score 5):

There are some misunderstandings here I think. Lets go through some of the particular points.

> In chapter 5, an example of multiple linear regression is used to eliminate the causal models inconsistent with the data.

I haven't looked at the text in a long while but I don't think that's quite right. Multiple linear regression is completely agnostic about causation. The causal model (i.e., a set of causal assumptions about the relations between variables) is encoded in the directed acyclic graph (DAG). It is formed with logic, external evidence, expert advice, etc. Crucially, it is formed from information *outside* of the data. The central idea is to fit and and interpret a regression model in light of the causal assumptions that the DAG encodes. I think you have things in reverse. We start with the causal model (DAG) and use that to inform the regression model. We do not use the regression model to confirm or refute the causal model.

> Using multiple linear regression, the consistent causal model, at least in this chapter, is that age influences both divorce rates and marriage rates such that when a regression model is constructed with age and marriage rates as predictors, the coefficient of marriage rate has uncertainty intervals that include 0. I.e. marriage rate is predictive but not causal.

There are a few sources of confusing here. Firstly, I wouldn't describe this as the 'consistent' causal model. The DAG which includes age as a common cause of marriage and divorce rates is the *proposed* causal model. But, relying as it does on uncertain assumptions, it may or may not represent the true causal structure generating the data. (As an aside, be wary that the term consistency has a quite specific meaning in both statistics and causal inference).

The underlying causal assumptions (encoded in the DAG) determine which variables ought to be included in the multiple regression model. This DAG identifies that age is a common cause of marriage and divorce rates (age is a confounder). So, including age in the regression model *adjusts* for this variable, removing that confounding bias.

You note that the interval includes zero. There is not really anything special about this value. It is one particular value across a range of possible values with which the data and model are more or less compatible. The fact that zero is within the interval does not mean that causation is absent.

> This got me wondering: if a model has poor predictive capabilities (say for exaggeration, the R2
> is less than 0.3 which, from what I read, is common in medicine). Let's suppose as well that when the residuals vs predicted values are plotted, there is no pattern, i.e. the assumptions of linear regression are reasonable. To what extent can we trust the causal implications of this model?

Predictive performance is really quite irrelevant to causal inference. Identifying and estimating causal effects from data requires a set of conditions (e.g., no unmeasured confounding, positivity, correct model specification,...) to be satisfied. Good predictive performance is not one of those conditions. You may be able to estimate causal effects without bias from a model with a very low $R^2$, it's really not very relevant.

The wider point here is that prediction and causal are really distinct goals and rely on different sets of assumptions. Have a look at the 'Prediction vs causal inference' section [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.10846.pdf).

Comment: While this is mostly right, just for the sake of completeness: Regression models can, in some circumstances, be used to identify causal models, as only a causally correct model will have constant error under interventions (c.f. [ICP](https://academic.oup.com/jrsssb/article/78/5/947/7040653)). For the same reason, predictive performance is not irrelevant to causal inference. Causal models should have stable predictive performance under interventions.

Comment: @Scriddie thanks for the reference. Very cool paper, I'll have to work through it

Comment: @Lachlan, thanks for the reply! I didn't claim that M <- A -> D is the correct causal model. One needs to incorporate science too. The emphasis of the post was using data to eliminate less plausible models. On p.134 of the 2nd ed, McElreath writes: "This tests the implication of the 2nd DAG from earlier. Since the first DAG did not imply this result, it is out."

I'll rephrase my question then. On this divorce example, suppose $R^2 = 0.3$. Can I still say that the first DAG is out? With what confidence?

Also, what are some methods to estimate causal effects without bias, as you mentioned?

Comment: @user1237300 ah I see. I haven't read the text in a while.  I guess he is using the data to test the (conditional) independencies implied by the DAG. That's not something I've ever really seen in an applied setting (not saying it's wrong). But I understand your point - what is the criterion to decide whether a DAG is 'out'? I don't know. As for causal inference methods, the book Causal Inference: What If will be a great companion to Rethinking

Comment: @Lachlan Thank you for the suggestion and the reference :)